# Error handling in class returns runtime error 440 "automation error"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class `ClsSubject` with the `let INN` property. The property checks wheither the incoming argument is a numeric string and has length of 10 characters. Otherwise it throws an error.

```
Property Let INN(val As String)
    If IsNumeric(val) And Len(val) = 10 Then
        PINN = val
    Else
        Dim errorMessage As String
        errorMessage = val & " is an Invalid value"
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "ClsSubject", errorMessage
    End If
End Property
```

When I try to simulate the error I only get

> Runtime error '440': Automation Error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you simulate the error? When I do that I get the expected error `invalid value`.

Comment: Usign `CallByName` sub, but I also made an example of @Vityata below in a new file, it just gave me different error description

Comment: I voted to close as _It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem._

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from the OP, the following works. In a module:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim x As New clsSubject
    x.INN = 3276132761#
    Debug.Print x.PINN

End Sub
```

And this in the class:

```
Public PINN As String

Property Let INN(val As String)
    If IsNumeric(val) And Len(val) = 10 Then
        PINN = val
    Else
        Dim errorMessage As String
        errorMessage = val & " is an Invalid value"

        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "ClsSubject", errorMessage
    End If
End Property
```

In order to make the code running, call `TestMe()`.

In the general case, the fields of the class should be private, and should be accessed through public properties. E.g. `private PINN as String`, but this is only for illustration.

Comment: I get `Runtime error -2147220991 (80040201) Automated Error: An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers`

Comment: @Igor Cheglakov: If you correctly copied the code, when enter a string like `x.INN = "YYY"` it will rise the next errror: `Run-time error '-2147220991 (80040201)': "YYY" is an Invalid value`. Exactly like it has been set in your class property...